# Как правильно говорить - трёмстам ТЫСЯЧАМ людей или трёмстам ТЫСЯЧ людей?

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Как правильно говорить - трёмстам ТЫСЯЧАМ людей или трёмстам ТЫСЯЧ людей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно говорить и писать "тысячам". Потому что (чему?)-"тысячам".